# How to change the gravatar image from front end?

Tags: gravatar

How can user change the own gravatar image from front end? for the back-end there are lot of plugins (like user photo etc.), by which user can easily change the gravatar image?

Comment: I think you mean avatar, not gravatar?

Comment: Please explain more precisely what you want to do.

Comment: i have created a custom form and i want that user can upload any picture from front-end and it will save on back-end and that image should be visible on profile page on back-end(yourdomain/wp-admin/profile.php)

Answer (score 0):

They can change the image in their [Gravatar account](http://en.gravatar.com/).

Or set a default from the backend which isn't what you asked originally

```
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults' , 'default_avatar' );

function default_avatar( $avatar_defaults ){

$new_avatar = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/default-gravatar.png';

$avatar_defaults[$new_avatar] = "Gravatar";

return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

Source [Replace default avatar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67304/replace-default-avatar)

Comment: yes i know that, can we change the gravatar image pragmatically?Is their a wordpress function for this?

Comment: Its based on the email address. You want to change it from the front end? The only way is to change the image on the account or change the email address submitted. http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars

Comment: yes i want to change it from front end, i am creating an user registration page on front-end from where user can change the gravatar image.

Comment: user can upload his custom image from front end and it should be saved as his gravatar image.

Comment: Not how Gravatar works as you upload the image from the front end of your Gravatar account. I think you're referring to allowing users to upload a Avatar image.

Comment: Try this for the front end http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24902/frontend-simple-local-avatar-upload

Comment: sorry it is not working.This code is for backend.

Comment: Did you try this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27252/9884

Comment: yes i tried this, it is only showing the image which we have uploaded from back-end..

Comment: this code is showing the error msg  "Call to undefined function wp_handle_upload()"